# Inserir uma lista em um banco de dados feito com o Django

Tags: python, django

Olá,eu quero inserir uma lista de nomes em um banco de dados que criei com o Django, porém não estou conseguindo. Existe algum método para inserir todos os nomes de uma vez? (Obs. Já realizei os comandos makemigrations e migrate)

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length = 50)
```

A lista que quero inserir é essa:

```
lista = ['André','Carla','João','Maria','Thelma','Ana']
```

Comment: Tens Bulk Insert... https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/01/09/django-bulk-inserts/

Answer (score 0):

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
  Entry(headline='This is a test'),
  Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
])
```

Só substituir pelo atributo (headline) que você quer, no seu caso `nome`

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Italo tem uma série de ressalvas, como por exemplo não funcionar em relacionamento muitos para muitos. [Veja na documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), então coloco mais uma opcao:

```
from <nome-do-pacote> import Usuario

lista = ['André','Carla','João','Maria','Thelma','Ana']
for nome in lista:
    Usuario.create(nome=nome)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para o bulk insert, já partilhei um link com um possível solução, mas utiliza uma classe e à primeira vista parace mais complicado, mas simplificando. Aqui fica a solução.

```
array_objects = []
lista = ['André','Carla','João','Maria','Thelma','Ana']
for nome in lista:
    array_objects.append(Usuario(nome=nome))
Usuario.objects.bulk_create(array_objects)
```